# Ubuntu Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: dns, openstack, cloud-init

I have downloaded a Ubuntu 20.04 cloud image from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/ and ran it as an instance in OpenStack. My OpenStack is also running on a VM using VMware. I have also assigned a floating IP address to my Ubuntu instance in OpenStack and I can ping external IP address successfully.

[ping 8.8.8.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04Uvc.png)

But when I ping google.com, I encounter the following error:

[ping google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POuA2.png)

I have tried all available solutions on the internet, but I am still unsuccessful. You can find some important configurations as follows:

> /etc/resolv.conf

[/etc/resolv.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRZJI.png)

It has a symlink with:

> ../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

[../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tbtN.png)

> /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

[/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T98X9.png)

Firewall Status:

> sudo ufw status -> Status: inactive

I have tried different versions of Ubuntu, and this problem was found in all of them.

Comment: did you try setting the nameserver to 8.8.8.8?

Comment: Yes, I did. But it didn't help. It just takes a few seconds more to show the error.